# Enable or disable LastModified column in apache mod_autoindex with fancyindex

Tags: apache, mod-autoindex

I am using `mod_autoindex` to give access to a hierarchy of files with an apache server. In most folders including the root folder, I don't want to display the "Last Modified" column, so I added the following in the `.htaccess` file in the root folder:

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing [...] SuppressLastmodified
```

The `[...]` stands for other options I omitted to avoid cluttering this post.

Further down in the folder hierarchy, there is a folder for which I *want* to display that column again.

I did not find any available option to revert for that folder the effect of `SuppressLastModified`.

I tried to put an `.htaccess` file in the subfolder with:

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing LastModified
```

or

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing +LastModified
```

Neither work, and the vim syntax highlighting did not recognize LastModified as a known keyword.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to do that? Many thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

I found the answer. Just adding a new `.htaccess` file in the subfolder with the original top-level `IndexOptions` with the `SuppressLastModified` *removed* does the trick.

Top-level folder `.htaccess` file contains:

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort HTMLTable SuppressLastmodified
```

Subfolder `.htaccess` file contains just:

```
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort HTMLTable
```